# How to replace string on load from resx-file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I have a lot of legacy code where string are loaded with

```
Strings.Name
```

In this strings are `\n` which replaced by

```
message = value?.Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine)
```

before rendered.

But before

```
string.Format(Strings.DirectoryDoesNotExist, directory)
```

The issue is if the directory path contains `\\n` (for example `c:\\new`) it will be at the end

```
c:
ew
```

So my question is: is it possible to replace/modify a string directly onLoad (in one method) from resx file?
So i dont need to fix a lot of legacy code.

Comment: Could you use console tools to change all the `*.resx` files. Or what kind of transformation do you want to do on the strings? For example you could provide how a string look before and after the transformation.

Comment: Also is it possible that in the same string are valid `\ ` chars and `\n`, like `somewhere\nowhere \n somemore text`

Comment: to change all the *.resx files is a possibility. My idea was to change the resx reader so after "line1 \n line2" in resx i get f.e. "line1 <newline/> line2". Then i could easily Replace("<newline/>", Environment.NewLine) before render

Comment: But what about the strings that conatin `\n` by coincidence, how do you want to sperate this cases in the resx loader?

Comment: that are audited by the translators so doesn't happen

Comment: I still don't quiet understand how you want to distinguish between the case of a normal backslash followed by an `n` and the deliberate sequence `\n` that should represent a newline. Could you maybe elaborate (in the question) on how you want to transform the strings loaded from an resx file and especially on the special case of a windows file path.